# ValueError in a Q&A like app for linking answers to question

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am learning to build a Q&A app using Django. I have set up models for posts, comments and users. I am not able to successfully link the `id` for the posts to the comments.

I have tried linking the comments to the posts by overriding the `ModelForm` on Django unsuccessfully.

This is in my `views.py` file:

```py
    class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['comment']

    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['post_id']
        return super(CommentCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

My models.py has the model for comments are follows:

```py
    class Comment(models.Model):
    cid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_id = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-home')
```

and my url path is as follows:

```
path('comment/<int:post_id>', PostCommentListView.as_view(), name='user-comments')
```

I expect the comments to get linked with the posts via the `ForeignKey`. But when I tried doing the same, I get an error as described below:

> ValueError at /post/11/comment/
> Cannot assign "11": "Comment.post_id" must be a "Post" instance.
>
> Exception Value:
> Cannot assign "11": "Comment.post_id" must be a "Post" instance.

Answer (score 0):

The error show that it expect an Post object. Try this

```
form.instance.post_id = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['post_id'])
```